# Phonegap WebIntent cannot open / access a downloaded APK file

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

From my Phonegap App I am downloading my APK which happens with no issues but I cannot get the file installed once its there.

The following bit of code just fails during the WEB INTENT section which should install the APk but its having trouble reading the file.

```js
var apkFilePath = cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory+'myapp.apk';
// Android UPDATE routine
function downloadApkAndroid(data) {
  var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
   permissions.hasPermission(permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, function (status) {
     if (!status.hasPermission) {
       var errorCallback = function () {
         alert("Error: app requires storage permission");
         if (callBack && callBack !== null) {
           callBack();
         }
       };
       permissions.requestPermission(permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
         function (status) {
           if (!status.hasPermission)
             errorCallback();
           else {
             downloadFile();
           }
         },
         errorCallback);
     }
     else {
       downloadFile();
     }
   }, null);
}

function downloadFile(){
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var url = "https://myappurl.com/myapp.apk";
  var uri = encodeURI(url);
  var filePath = getFilePath();

  fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    apkFilePath,
    function (entry) {
      console.log("Download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
      promptForUpdateAndroid(entry);
    },
    function (error) {
      console.error("Download error source " + error.source);
      console.error("Download error target " + error.target);
      console.error("Download error code " + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {

    }
  );
}


/*
 * Uses the borismus webintent plugin
 */
 function promptForUpdateAndroid(entry) {
  console.log(apkFilePath);
  window.plugins.webintent.startActivity(
    {
      action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
      url: apkFilePath,
    type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
  },
  function () {
  },
  function () {
    // alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent.');
    console.log("Failed to open URL via Android Intent. URL: " + entry.fullPath);
  }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So figured this out by using [cordova-plugin-file-opener2](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) and changing the `promptForUpdateAndroid()` to get rid of Web Intents:

```js
var myFilePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory+'myApp.apk';

function promptForUpdateAndroid(entry) {
  cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    myFilePath,
    'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
    {
      error : function(e) {
      console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
    },
    success : function () {
      console.log('file opened successfully');
    }
  }
);
```

This instantly installed the app, though it didn't re-open once installed. I'm off to figure that out.